# Consuming WCF Data Service - getting error "Operation could not be completed"

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

Whenever I attempt to consume WCF Data Service (version 5.0 of WCF Data Services), the proxy generation fails with the error message:

The operation could not be completed

Any ideas? The Data Service is built using VS2012, Entity Framework 5.0 and WCF Data Services 5.0. Client is Windows 8 built using VS2012.

I have also tried installing WCF Data service 5.3 installer but faces same issue.

Comment: You might consider enabling tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service and get to know the exact error by inspecting the trace file.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I was facing issues on the entities which had a timespan datatype and throwed a "Operation cannot be completed" error while consuming the WCF data service in a Windows Store Client Library.

So the solution to the issue whilst consuming the WCF Data service to Windows Store app is to install the "WCF Data Services 5.6.0 Alpha Tools Installer" available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373)

Installing this resolved the issues faced while consuming the service.